# if clip rect is depreciated is there a favored alternative?

Tags: html, css

**Is there a favored alternative to clip rect that isn't deprecated?**

The clip-path property in CSS allows you to specify a specific region of an element to display, rather than showing the complete area. There used to be a clip property, but note that is **deprecated**.

[Clip Rect Docs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp)

Comment: clip-path isn't deprecated and replaces clip, or am I missing something? See http://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking-1/#clip-property

Comment: This question is completely legitime since most of website deprecated the clip rect without proposing a replacement. It's even used in many recents tutorials. (y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `clip rect()` is deprecated, then the `clip sector` is still very useful, as you can clip polygons, circles, etc, using the `clip-path` selector, as [described](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/) here. This is also sometimes refereed to as CSS masking.